# check session and change menu when 3 sessions are possible

Tags: php, mysql, session

How can I code $_SESSION to have three possible conditions?

These are the three possible types of conditions, the session can be student, corporate and institute:

```
if($_SESSION['user_id'] && $_SESSION['user_type']=="student"){
else if($_SESSION['user_id'] && $_SESSION['user_type']=="corporate"){
else if($_SESSION['user_id'] && $_SESSION['user_type']=="institute"){
```

If any of those sessions are there I want to show a profile buttons else a register button.

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION())){?>
<a href="my-profile.php"><input type="button" value="VISIT YOUR PROFILE"></a>
<?php }else{ ?>
<a href="signup.php"><input type="button" value="REGISTER NOW"></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I don't understand. Please explain more

Comment: You forgot to mention what the problem is.

Comment: if session is there menu has to replace same like we do for login and logout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to accomplish:

```
if($_SESSION['user_type']=="student" || $_SESSION['user_type']=="corporate" || $_SESSION['user_type']=="institute") {
    echo '<a href="my-profile.php"><input type="button" value="VISIT YOUR PROFILE"></a>'; 
}
else {
    echo '<a href="signup.php"><input type="button" value="REGISTER NOW"></a>';
}
```

If `user_type` is student, corporate or institute they will be able to visit their profile through the available button. Anyone else will see the register button.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])): ?>
// Logged-in users  
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION["user_type"]) && $_SESSION["user_type"] == "student"): ?>
        // student
    <?php elseif (isset($_SESSION["user_type"]) && $_SESSION["user_type"] == "corporate"): ?>
        // corporate
    <?php elseif (isset($_SESSION["user_type"]) && $_SESSION["user_type"] == "institute"): ?>
        // institute
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    // REGISTER NOW
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

While you're question is not very well put, i think you're asking for this?

```
$sessionValid = ($_SESSION['user_id'] ? ($_SESSION['user_type'] == "student" ? true : ($_SESSION['user_type'] == "corporate" ? true : ($_SESSION['institute'] ? true : false) : false ) : false ) : false)
if ( $sessionValid )
{
    //No login needed
} else {
    //Register today!
}
```